# How to find the longest full name of a person in a json file?

Tags: python, json, extract, data-analysis

I'm working on a json file, with the data given as seen below:

```
{"id":"Q47786519","name":"Ulrik Luft","l":"-1684","p":"","g":"m","y":1664,"o":["Q12323666"]}
```

What I want to do is to write a code, that gives me the longest full name of a person in my json file. So far I wrote the following:

```
file = open("dbl.json")
dbl = json.load(file)

def longest_name_born(persons):

    longest_name = persons[0]
    for person in persons:
            if len(person['name']) > len(longest_name['name']):
                longest_name = person
    return longest_name['p']

print(longest_name_born(dbl))
```

But it only gives me the longest single name `(Augustenborg`) in the file and not the longest full name. Can some help me/ give me a hint?

Comment: Why does your function return the `p` member and not `name`?

Comment: Wow that was the problem.. Thank you :) Think i just got blind.

Answer (score 0):

Your code isn’t perfect, but it’s correct and should give you the longest string in the name attribute of the collection.

Maybe Augustenborg (12 chars) is longest? It’s longer than your pasted example Ulrik Luft

Comment: I looked up "Augustenborg" and his full name is "Emil af Slesvig-Holsten-Sønderborg-Augustenborg".